# How to represent tabular data in C# which has generic datatypes in a variable number of columns?

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following C# solution using generics for representing tabular data which has different datatypes in each column. The ultimate goal is to compare the datapoints of any two tables, which is why the columns have a constraint that they implement IComparable.  My difficulty is in scaling it so that it can support any number of columns the user wishes:

```
class TableObject<RowHeaderType, Column1Type, Column2Type>
    where Column1Type : IComparable
    where Column2Type : IComparable
{
    List<string> columnHeaders;
    Dictionary<RowHeaderType, Dictionary<string, IComparable>> tableDict;
    Dictionary<string, IComparable> rowDict;

    public TableObject(List<string> _columnHeaders)
    {
        tableDict = new Dictionary<RowHeaderType, Dictionary<string, IComparable>>();
        columnHeaders = _columnHeaders;

    }

    public void addRow(RowHeaderType rowHeader, Column1Type colvalue_1, Column2Type colvalue_2)
    {
        // rowDict represents one row, with each key/value representing a column of data
        rowDict = new Dictionary<string, IComparable>();

        rowDict.Add(columnHeaders[1], colvalue_1); // [0] was the row header table 
        rowDict.Add(columnHeaders[2], colvalue_2);

        // add this new row to the master table
        tableDict.Add(rowHeader, rowDict);
    }

}
```

In the constructor I pass in a List which are the column labels. Then I would call addRows which would take (ideally) a rowHeaderType value, and an array which would represent the values which make up the entire row, each corresponding to the columnType defined.

My goal is make this as generic as possible. The only restriction I have here is that the column names are strings since I ultimately wish to display this in a datagridview.

If there is an alternate design which you feel is better, please feel free to suggest that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know about [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx)s, [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)s, [`DataColumn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.aspx)s and [`DataRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx)s?

You can even work with [typed data sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esbykkzb.aspx). There's a lot of existing support for them.